# pyinstaller with customtkinter: exception when running exe --> AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'CTk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, customtkinter

I have created a Python script, which uses customtkinter for a GUI where the user can select some options.

Here is an overview about the imported packages:
[used libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubO2q.png)

Everything works properly when I run the script in Pycharm (Community Edition 2021.1.2) and the GUI shows up as expected.

But after building (creating an exe from the script) using pyinstaller and running the exe I get following error message:
[Error when running exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOIyq.png)

Line 403 makes a problem acc. to this message - the corresponding line in the script looks like:
[Line 403 causes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLMW3.png)

For building the exe I use following command:
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data c:\users\myName\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\customtkinter;customtkinter\ DataAnalysisTool.py

Hope somebody can help!

I would expect that the exe file also runs as the script in Pycharm runs without any problem.

**Update:** minimum reproducible example (throws same error message when running exe)

```
import customtkinter

# create the root window
root_file = customtkinter.CTk()
root_file.title('Data Analysis Tool - File Selection')
root_file.resizable(False, False)
root_file.geometry('350x150')

root_file.mainloop()
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/Packaging#windows-pyinstaller-auto-py-to-exe). You have to do like ```--add-data "c:/users/myName/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages/customtkinter;customtkinter/"```

Comment: @Alexander: I added a minimal reproducible example - see above.

Comment: @relent95: that's what I already tried - see command what I used to build the exe.

Comment: I take it relent95 tip didn't help then?

Comment: exactly, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to compile your example code with the following steps:

1. Create a new virtual environment and install `customtkinter` and `pyinstaller`
2. create a main.py file with your example code.

```
import customtkinter

# create the root window
root_file = customtkinter.CTk()
root_file.title('Data Analysis Tool - File Selection')
root_file.resizable(False, False)
root_file.geometry('350x150')

root_file.mainloop()
```

3. run `pyinstaller -F main.py --collect-all customtkinter`

The compiled executable runs without error.

It works using the `--onedir` option as well.